# guavaRateLimter vs ExecutorService for rateLimiting 3p api calls

Tags: java, guava, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have use case where i need to call 3p service as per traffic agrement like 1000 request per hour

I have two solutions for this

guavaRateLimter

```
hashmap<String,RateLimiter> rateWebsiteMap = new HashMap<>();
rateWebsiteMap.add(amazon:10Request)
rateWebsiteMap.add(google:20Request)
while(true){
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        website = entry.getKey()
        rateLimit = entry.getValue()
        if(ratelimter.tryAcquire()){
            triggercall(website)
        }
    }
}
```

Or using ScheduledExecutorService

```
    ScheduledExecutorService es = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(100);
   Future<Object1> =  es.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            triggercall(websiteAmazon);
    }, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

   hashmap<String,Future<Object1>> FutureWebsiteMap = new HashMap<>();
   FutureWebsiteMap.add(amazon:AmazonFuture) //If i want to cancel that thread
```

As far as i read i am getting mixed reviews like some posts suggesting to use guava-rateLimiter inside infinite while-loop with sleeptime. Some posts/blogs suggesting to use ScheduledExecutorService.

How do i benchmark the perfoemance of both. which one will be best fit for my usecase.
I have a requirement to change the traffic when ever it is required. thats why storing future in map so that I can cancel and reschedule with new timer.

which approach will use less cpu/memory

I am using java-11

Comment: At 1000 requests per hour, I would be surprised if there were any significant performance or memory difference... Also there is no need for "sleeptime" with Ratelimiter.

Comment: In real world i have some api 100 request per seconds and some are 1000 per day. That infinite while loop (rateLimiter) running contineously wont impact anything ?